# Concatenate strings on a single column on a data grid

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

Good day,

I just have a problem regarding the vb.net data grid. I want to combine all the cell column value and put it on a string.

Data grid values

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 110 |
| 2 | 120 |
| 3 | 130 |

Require output on a textbox

Textbox1 = 110-120-130

I know it's a simple problem but can't find it on google that's why I'm hoping some of the veterans here can solve my problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of trying to find code to copy and paste, how about you put some thought into it? The biggest issue that most beginners have is that they treat what's in front of them as a single unit and want to find code to do just that thing. That's not how to solve programming problems. In this case, you can break the problem down into at least two parts: getting data out of the grid and combining multiple strings into one. I find it very hard to believe that you can't at least work how to each in isolation and, once you can do that, you just put the two together and you're done.

Comment: Wow. Didnt think about tha, Thank you for the reminder

Comment: Programming is all about taking basic things you know and combining them in novel ways to do something new. ALWAYS break your problem down into the smallest parts possible and then tackle each part individually. One you solve each partial problem, the combined solution inherently solves the original problem. If there is one specific part that can't work out, even after researching, then you should ask about that part specifically. Your question here is about at least two parts though, so you have more work to do to break the problem down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no idea what a datagrid is but i'm sure its based on some repeating structure, like a datatable, list or 2D array

When you want to build a string using repeated concatenation you use a stringbuilder

```
Dim sb as New StringBuilder
```

The Append methods return the stringbuilder itself so you can call Append().Append()...

```
sb.Append("130").Append("-")
```

When you want to do something repeatedly you use a loop over the collection of things

```
For Each ro as DataRow in someDataTable.Rows

Next ro
```

So you can put a call inside the loop to get the data you want and put it into the stringbuilder

```
For Each ro as DataRow in someDataTable.Rows
  sb.Append(ro("Code")).Append("-")
Next ro
```

If you change the Length of a stringbuilder it cuts the end of the string off

```
sb.Length -= 1
```

To turn a stringbuilder into a string, you use its `.ToString()` function

You now have all the tools you need to solve your problem. FOr the avoidance of doubt, it's virtually certain you cannot just copy paste this code and have it solve your problem. You absolutely must keep brain engaged, understand what this answer is teaching and modify it so it applies to your situation